# Search Scopes in SharePoint 2013 with 2010 compatibility mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I was wondering, is it possible to programmatically create search scopes for SharePoint 2013 when my Site Collections are created in 2010 compatibility mode? I was trying to use code that we used for SharePoint 2010 and got an error at `ScopeCollection.Create` saying

> This operation is not supported

I know it got depreciated for SharePoint 2013, but maybe it is possible with a 2010 mode Site Collection because I saw the possibility to manually add a scope.